# Compare two version of files and apply changes to older file

Tags: c#, algorithm, file-comparison

I've been searching & googling a lot about this question, and I already know how to compare two files (hashes, checksums, etc.). But it's not quite what I need. What I need is described below.

Lets assume I have a file and I've backuped it. Later I've made some changes to this file, so I want to apply changes to the backup version. Since two files can be big enought and changes can be small, I don't want to rewrite all the file, because I'm planning to backup it though the internet (maybe FTP) wich can take a lot of time.

How I see this (sample):

Backup version of file (bytes)

```
134 253 637 151
```

Newer version of file (bytes)

```
134 624 151 890
```

Instead of rewriting all bytes, we should:

1. change `253` to `624` (change bytes)
2. remove `637` bytes (remove bytes)
3. write `890` at the end of file (insert bytes)

The 1,2,3 options do not necessarily appear at once in each case.
Note that the backup file could be located somewhere else, and I only have acces to it through the internet (server could return something so we can compare files).

How can I achive this? I know it's possible cause I know software where it's implemented (but couldn't find out how).
Any hints, tutorials, etc. is welcomed and highly appriciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked out the implementation of `diff`? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff)

Comment: yep, I've seen this, and I know I can find the difference, but I don't actually understand how sohuld I transfer some bytes and force them to be inserted in specific place... should I transfer these bytes with additional place number?

Comment: Are you comparing text or binary info - you might want to look into the algorithms behind binary diff tools like http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/

Comment: Um, isn't this the same as just overwriting the backup with the new version?

Comment: Slugart - both files can be present | 
Raymond Chen - nope, it's just swapping changed bytes. if file of 2GB changed with few bytes, I'm not forced to transfer 2GB, just these few bytes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to solve the same problem that every MMORPG has solved... creating and applying small patch files to update older versions of large binaries.

This is a well-studied problem and there are a number of solutions out there.  For several existing options, see

[Binary patch-generation in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831/binary-patch-generation-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I understand that I can also apply it to make my software updatable?

Comment: Yes, in fact Windows Installer can generate patch files (as can a number of other open source and commercial solutions).